# How to select rows where values changed for an ID

Tags: sql, database, subquery, mysql-workbench

I have a table that looks like the following

```
id         effective_date    number_of_int_customers
123        10/01/19            0
123        02/01/20            3
456        10/01/19            6
456        02/01/20            6
789        10/01/19            5
789        02/01/20            4
999        10/01/19            0
999        02/01/20            1
```

I want to write a query that looks at each ID to see if the salespeople have newly started working internationally between October 1st and February 1st.

The result I am looking for is the following:

```
id         effective_date    number_of_int_customers
123        02/01/20            3 
999        02/01/20            1
```

The result would return only the salespeople who originally had 0 international customers and now have at least 1.
I have seen similar posts here that use nested queries to pull records where the first date and last have different values. But I only want to pull records where the original value was 0. Is there a way to do this in one query in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, a simple aggregation would do -- assuming that `0` is the earliest value:

```
select id, max(number_of_int_customers)
from t
where effective_date in ('2019-10-01', '2020-02-01')
group by id
having min(number_of_int_customers) = 0;
```

Obviously, this is not correct if the values can decrease to zero.  But this `having` clause fixes that problem:

```
having min(case when number_of_int_customers = 0 then effective_date end) = min(effective_date)
```

An alternative is to use window functions, such as`first_value()`:

```
select distinct id, last_noic
from (select t.*,
             first_value(number_of_int_customers) over (partition by id order by effective_date) as first_noic,
             first_value(number_of_int_customers) over (partition by id order by effective_date desc) as last_noic,
      from t
      where effective_date in ('2019-10-01', '2020-02-01')
     ) t
where first_noic = 0;
```

Hmmm, on second thought, I like `lag()` better:

```
select id, number_of_int_customers
from (select t.*,
             lag(number_of_int_customers) over (partition by id order by effective_date) as prev_noic
      from t
      where effective_date in ('2019-10-01', '2020-02-01')
     ) t
where prev_noic = 0;
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much for this. I was honestly not aware of the lag function or partition for that matter (started watching some videos on Youtube to learn about these two). But this does exactly what I need it to do. Thank you again!